# Многопоточность с multiprocessing + json

Tags: python, json, многопоточность, multiprocessing

Программа используется для огромного кол-ва итераций. Для этого использовал библиотеку multiprocessing. Создал несколько параллельных потоков для большей эффективности, но при записи данных в json файл и их обработки, ломается сам json-файл, в которые записываются данные. Из-за того, что файл открыт сразу в нескольких потоках, он и сохраняется и сразу изменяется и т.д. Получается так, что в одном потоке json-файл открыт, а в другом уже изменился и сохранился. Появляются лишние [] и {} скобки, из-за чего файл становится не читабельный и все это приводит к ошибке: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0). Пытался использовать multiprocessing.Lock(), но все равно не помогает, файл все также ломается.
Вот код запуска программы:

```
def process_item_wrapper(args):
    process_item(*args)


def main():
    start_time = time.time()
    items_list = read_json('winfo.json')
    collections_ = read_json('Collections.json')
    name_to_item = {item['name']: item for item in items_list}

    num_cores = 8  # Установите количество доступных ядер процессора

    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=num_cores) as pool:
        list(tqdm(pool.imap_unordered(process_item_wrapper, [(item, collections_, name_to_item, items_list) for item in items_list]), total=len(items_list)))

    end_time = time.time()
    print(f"Execution time: {end_time - start_time} seconds")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Проблемная часть кода:

```
lock = multiprocessing.Lock()

def check_on_max_percentage_change(percentage, info_dict):
    with lock:
        profitable_data = read_json('profitable.json')

        if not profitable_data[0]['max-profitable']:
            profitable_data[0]['max-profitable'].append({'percentage': percentage, 'data': info_dict})
        else:
            for i in range(len(profitable_data[0]['max-profitable'])):
                if profitable_data[0]['max-profitable'][i]['percentage'] < percentage:
                    profitable_data[0]['max-profitable'].insert(i, {'percentage': percentage, 'data': info_dict})
                    break
                else:
                    profitable_data[0]['max-profitable'].append({'percentage': percentage, 'data': info_dict})
                    break

        if len(profitable_data[0]['max-profitable']) > 10:
            del profitable_data[0]['max-profitable'][10:]

        write_json('profitable.json', profitable_data)


def get_most_profitable_contracts(info_dict):
    cost_craft = info_dict["item"]["price"] * 1 + info_dict["additional_item"]["price"] * 9
    profits = []
    chances = []
    percentage_arr = []
    for item in range(len(info_dict['dropped_items'])):
        percentage = round(calculate_percentage_change(cost_craft, info_dict["dropped_items"][item]["price"]), 2)
        percentage_arr.append(percentage)
        profits.append(percentage)
        chances.append(round(info_dict["dropped_items"][item]["chance"]))
    check_on_max_percentage_change(max(percentage_arr), info_dict)
    weights = [chance / 100 for chance in chances]
    weighted_average = sum(p * w for p, w in zip(profits, weights)) / sum(weights)
    info_dict['profitable'] = weighted_average
    return info_dict
```

Comment: В смысле — ломается? В чем именно состоит неправильное поведение программы?

Comment: @Глеб , ломается сам json файл, в которые записываются данные. Из-за того, что файл открыт сразу в нескольких потоках, он и сохраняется и сразу изменяется и т.д. Получается так, что в одном потоке json-файл открыт, а в другом уже изменился и сохранился. Появляются лишние [] и {} скобки, из-за чего файл становится не читабельный и появляется ошибка:
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: Вставьте эту информацию в вопрос.

Comment: json не получится формировать в несколько потоков/несколькими процессами. Данные можно подготовить в нескольких процессах, но запись в файл нужно делать одним процессом.

Comment: @insolor, знаю, для этого и хотел использовать lock, но почему-то и с ним не получается.

Comment: А `read_json` и `write_json` файлы закрывать не забывают?

Comment: Да хоть с локом, хоть без лока. Даже если вы просто в одном потоке несколько раз в файл json запишите, он будет некорректным. Нужно сначала данные собрать, потом один раз, одним json.dump записать. Из imap получаете весь результат, потом собираете в один список, и весь этот список конвертируете в json и сохраняете.

Comment: @insolor, понял, спасибо, то есть, json в данном случае не использовать, а лучше взять БД, тот же sqlite3?

Comment: @CrazyElf, вот их логика выполнения:
`
def read_json(name_json):
    with open(name_json, 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    return data
`

`
def write_json(name_json, data):
    with open(name_json, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
`

Comment: Да, можно бд. sqlite - туда вроде одним потоком можно писать, насколько я помню. Но если настоящая параллельная запись не нужна, то можно и его использовать (запись локом накрыть). Да даже csv наверное можно использовать, записывать построчно, после каждой записи flush делать, ну и локами обложить. csv тут лучше подойдет (чем json), потому что нет сложной структуры (типа открывающих/закрывающих скобок в начале и конце).

Comment: @insolor, хорошо, спасибо, учту.

Comment: @insolor Насчёт БД бешено плюсую, и сам писал об этом в предыдущем аналогичном вопросе, которого копия этот вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Как минимум, вы неправильно работаете с локом. Вот пример из [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html):

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = Lock()

    for num in range(10):
        Process(target=f, args=(lock, num)).start()
```

Тут очень важно, что `lock` объект инстанциируется один раз и передаётся аргументом во все процессы. У вас же, если вы предоставили релевантный код, на каждый процесс создаётся свой отдельный `lock` и, конечно, он в этом случае ни от чего не защищает. `lock` конкретного процесса ничего не знает об остальных `lock` других процессов.

Comment: Да, теперь все работает, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Вот изменённый и рабочий вариант кода:

```
def main():
    start_time = time.time()
    items_list = read_json('winfo.json')
    collections_ = read_json('Collections.json')
    name_to_item = {item['name']: item for item in items_list}

    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    lock = manager.RLock()

    num_cores = 8  # Установите количество доступных ядер процессора

    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=num_cores) as pool:
        list(tqdm(pool.imap_unordered(process_item_wrapper, [(item, collections_, name_to_item, items_list, lock) for item in items_list]), total=len(items_list)))

    end_time = time.time()
    print(f"Execution time: {end_time - start_time} seconds")
```

Добавил в main создание блокировщика, и передаю его через аргументы функций до check_on_max_percentage_change(). Учту, что просто multiprocessing.RLock() не будет работать, т.к. RLock() не может быть общим процессом. Для этого использовал multiprocessing.Manager(), чтобы создать разделяемый объект между процессами.

```
def check_on_max_percentage_change(percentage, info_dict, lock):
    with lock:
        profitable_data = read_json('profitable.json')

        if not profitable_data[0]['max-profitable']:
            profitable_data[0]['max-profitable'].append({'percentage': percentage, 'data': info_dict})
        else:
            for i in range(len(profitable_data[0]['max-profitable'])):
                if profitable_data[0]['max-profitable'][i]['percentage'] < percentage:
                    profitable_data[0]['max-profitable'].insert(i, {'percentage': percentage, 'data': info_dict})
                    break
                else:
                    profitable_data[0]['max-profitable'].append({'percentage': percentage, 'data': info_dict})
                    break

        if len(profitable_data[0]['max-profitable']) > 10:
            del profitable_data[0]['max-profitable'][10:]

        write_json('profitable.json', profitable_data)
```